# how to combine joptionpane with combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, joptionpane

i want my `joptionpane` can combine with `combobox`,and the combobox data is in database, how i managed that.

i've tried change but the red code always show

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String wel = sdf.format(cal1.getDate());
                String NamaFile = "/report/harianMasuk.jasper";
                HashMap hash = new HashMap();
          String tak = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,id.getSelectedIndex()-1,"Laporan Supplier",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
     try {
                      hash.put("til", wel);
                   hash.put("rul", tak);  
                   runReportDefault(NamaFile, hash);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
               }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Getting User Input From a Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input).

It demonstrates how to display a combo box in a `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish but it appears to be that you want to utilize a JComboBox within a **JOptionPane** dialog window. This ComboBox would be filled with specific data from your database. The User is to select from this ComboBox and your application continues processing based on that selection. If this is the case then you might want to try something like this:

```
String selectedItem = "";
int selectedItemIndex = -1;

/* Ensure dialog never hides behind anything (use if
   the keyword 'this' can not be used or there is no 
   object to reference as parent for the dialog).   */
JFrame iframe = new JFrame();
iframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
iframe.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
// ---------------------------------------------------

int btns = JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION;

String dialogMessage = "<html>Select the desired item from the Drop-Down "
        + "list<br>you want to work with:<br><br></html>";
String dialogTitle = "Your Fav Items";
/* Up to you to gather what you want placed into the
   JComboBox that will be displayed within the JOptionPane. */
String[] comboBoxItems = {"Your", "DB", "Items", "You", "Want", "To",
    "Add", "To", "ComboBox"};
BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(layout);
JLabel label = new JLabel(dialogMessage);
topPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();
cb.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(comboBoxItems));
cb.setSelectedIndex(-1);
centerPanel.add(cb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
topPanel.add(centerPanel);

// Ensure a selection or Cancel (or dialog close)
while (selectedItemIndex < 0) {
    int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(iframe, topPanel, dialogTitle, btns);
    if (res == 2) {
        selectedItem = "Selection Option Was Canceled!";
        break;
    }
    selectedItemIndex = cb.getSelectedIndex();
    if (res == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        if (selectedItemIndex == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iframe, "<html>You <b>must</b> "
                    + "select something or select <font color=red><b>Cancel</b></font>.",
                      "Invalid Selection...", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        else {
            selectedItem = cb.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
    }
    iframe.dispose();
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iframe, "<html>You selected the ComboBox item:"
        + "<br><br><b><font color=blue><center>" + selectedItem + "</center>"
        + "</font></b><br></html>", "Selected Item", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
iframe.dispose();
```

With the above code, the Input dialog that will be displayed would look something like this:

[image]

[image]

It is up to you to find the means to fill the **comboBoxItems** String Array used within the code above.